# Jquery ajax not hitting server

Tags: asp.net, jquery, get

I have an htm page and and one service.aspx and service.aspx.cs file in my current application. I am using .Net 4.0. in service.aspx.cs page I have testmethod as below.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static string test()
{
    return "AA";
}
```

In my html page

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "NextGenFormService.aspx/test",
    dataType: "xml",
    contentType: "text/html",
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});  //end of $.ajax;
```

If I keep a break point in my server it is not hitting. AjaxSucceeded is getting called with 200 OK and the responseText is empty.

The same works with contenttype: application/json, datatype: json.

What I am trying to send from server or the test method is nothing but html and JavaScript.

Comment: have checked your url in a browser is it working ?

Comment: Try installing Fiddler2 to monitor your requests. What does it say about that request?

Comment: The fiddler response is coming empty.

Comment: does it have anything to do with cross domain? but why the same is working with json datatype and contenttype.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default `contentType` as you are sending nothing, change to `html` datatype.

Sometimes asp.net does not like a missing data property, even an empty one like so:

```
$.ajax({
    data:{},
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: "NextGenFormService.aspx/test",
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;",
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```